# Is there a simple way to specify a WPF databinding where the path is one "level" up?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, relative-path

This example is a admittedly a little contrived but I am doing something similar. Let's say I have the following simple classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Alias> Aliases { get; set; }
}

public class Alias
{
    public string AliasName { get; set; }
}
```

And let's say that I have Xaml with a LayoutRoot grid, and a DataGrid where I want to access the Name property within the DataGrid **instead** of the Aliases properties like in the second column here:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="PersonInstance">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Aliases}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="AliasName" Binding="{Binding AliasName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding ../Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

That is intuitively how I would attempt to bind the name, but needless to say that looks stupid. Is there something like that when specifying a path, or are you forced to get a relative source up to the LayoutRoot data context.  If you have to, what's the most efficient way?

Comment: Why isn't this working? `Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: @Veer, because there is no Name property in the class Alias...

Comment: @Anvaka: But the datacontext is set the instance of person class. It should know the Name property.

Comment: @Veer: Oh, you are right! Missed it. But we are using Aliases as ItemsSource doesn't that mean we'll have Alias in the row's DataContext? Even if it's not, then AliasName won't work...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work for you :

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" 
                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                                      FindAncestor,
                                                      AncestorLevel=3, 
                                                      AncestorType={x:Type Grid},
                                                    Path=DataContext.Name}"/>
```

You can use any of the following :

To make the source element equal the closest parent of a given type:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type
desiredType}}}
```

To make the source element equal the nth closest parent of a given type:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
AncestorLevel=n, AncestorType={x:Type desiredType}}}
```

To make the source element equal the previous data item in a data-bound collection:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}
```

Comment: This is outrageously verbose. Your first example ought to be written `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,Grid,3}}`. The others should be simplified as well. Anyone who understands FindAncestor's function will understand `FindAncestor,Grid,3` just as easily as your four lines of code, and with less thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no better way to do this than using relative source up the tree. You could rewrite your model (for example, add a reference to parent `Person` from `Alias`) but that's hardly better approach.

From performance prospective I never found bottlenecks in relative source bindings. There's always something else that keeps your app away from rocket speed.